# Manage caching of large dataset in resource limited browser (mobile)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, caching, xmlhttprequest

## The Question

How can I manage large sets of filtered, sorted, paginated data in a single-page app which must also be functional on resource-limited devices (eg; mobile)?

More specifically; I have a dataset of 1000+ geocoded place information objects which is filtered to those contained within a map viewport. Due to memory constraints on mobile, I cannot cache the entire dataset. However, due to slow network connections on mobile, I want to minimise HTTP requests.

What is the best strategy for the combination of maximum caching and minimum network requests?

---

## Some Context

I am building a map split-view for a potentially large (1000+) dataset of information in Australia:

```
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                                        |             +----------+    |
|                                        |    Sort By: |Suburb |\/|    |
|                                        |             +----------+    |
|                                        |+---------------------------+|
|                _,__        .:          ||                           ||
|               <*  /        | \         ||  Blah Blah                ||
|           .-./     |.     :  :,        ||                           ||
|          /           '-._/     \_      ||  Zoom Zip                 ||
|         /                '       \     ||                           ||
|       .'                         *:    |+---------------------------+|
|    .-'                             ;   |+---------------------------+|
|    |                               |   ||                           ||
|    \                              /    ||  Bing Bong                ||
|     |                            /     ||                           ||
|      \*        __.--._          /      ||  Banana for scale         ||
|       \     _.'       \:.       |      ||                           ||
|       >__,-'             \_/*_.-'      |+---------------------------+|
|                                        |+---------------------------+|
|                            :--,        ||                           ||
|                             '/         ||  Whoopty Doo              ||
|                                        ||                           ||
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Driving requirements are:

- Must work on old/slow mobile / tablet as well as modern desktops.
- Must be able to scroll through *entire* dataset in the right-hand list.
- Must be able to filter the list by moving / zooming the map.
- Must be able to alter the sort order (by location, name, id, etc).

---

## What I've Tried

I have gone through a couple of iterations of handling the data in the app*:

### Iteration 1 (Naive)

- *Load the entire list of data into memory and render it all at once.*

The problems arise with memory constraints on mobile due to each item in the list potentially containing a large set of data each (in JSON format).

There are also other considerations with overloading the DOM when loading the entire list in at once (render time in the browser makes the app unusable).

### Iteration 2 (Lazy Loading)

- *Implement lazy-loaded infinite scroll (a-la Twitter / Facebook).*

Doing this a "page" at a time (where a page is ~30 items), we solve the initial memory requirement, but after scrolling so far we hit the limits again on mobile.

There is also a network requirement on mobile now - GPRS/EDGE speeds are unfortunately still common in Australia, and really suck.

### Iteration 3 (Data unloading)

- *Unload old data from memory / DOM to keep things moving fast*

Old DOM elements can be replaced with empty placeholders (to keep the affordance of scrolling), and the associated items in the list can be removed from memory. This solves the DOM limitations issue.

However, we have now doubled our network load if the user scrolls back up the list. Ie; there is no cached data anymore.

### Iteration 4 (Cache & Lazy unload)

- *Cache X number of old results (where X can be determined by the memory capabilities of the device), unloading on a FIFO basis.*

So our cache can now stay warm, and scrolling back should be an instant load with no network requests.

But what if the user alters the filters / sorting criteria? A single cache is no longer effective as the results in the list may need to be re-filtered and re-sorted for display.

Since the dataset is lazy loaded, the app does not have a complete dataset to correctly perform the filter and sort, so a HTTP request is required.

The worst case is when a user pans the map slightly. 1-2 items may fall off one side, while 2-3 might be added on the opposite side. Now, instead of re-using any possibly cached data, we are unnecessarily reloading over a network request.

### Iteration 5 (delta results)

- *Pass a list of already-known `id`s with the request, and only receive the delta of the results*

This saves data being downloaded over the wire. However, may result in large amounts of data being sent *up* the wire so the API can perform the delta.

### Iteration 6 (known ranges)

- *Never re-request data that falls within a known range*

Ranges could be a sub-set of the visible bounding box (think spatial partitioning), or a "page" of 30 results when scrolling, etc.

This solves the problem of too much network traffic (both up and down), but I am afraid that the meta data required for storing known ranges may also reach memory limits on a mobile device.

### Iteration 7 (degrade functionality)

- *Remove the requirement that the entire list must be scrollable.*

By removing this requirement, we can limit the results we show to a maximum of, say, 50-100, and stick with the **Iteration 1 (Naive)** approach when we are running on a device detected as limited in capabilities.

---

## The Question (again)

How can I manage large sets of filtered, sorted, paginated data in a single-page app which must also be functional on resource-limited devices (eg; mobile)?

---

* *Note: I have already figured out the rendering of the data on the map by using a clustering technique based on the current zoom level, so this is not an issue*

Comment: This belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: "does not appear to be about *programming*". belongs on **programmers**.stackexchange.com. I don't mind moving it, but want to make sure it's going to the correct place. Also, I'm not sure why 13 people think it's not about programming - it's about caching data and network transfer of that data in a browser-side application...

Comment: I have clarified the question - is it possible to reopen?

Comment: +infinity for ASCII Art. +1 for Sydney not being included but Melbourne being included. (please don't edit it, after my comment :) ) +1 for Banana + Img.ur reference.

Comment: Can you maybe get users to install Opera mini? It's more of a set& forget approach... http://www.opera.com/mobile/mini/other

Comment: Maybe create smaller sets of the same data? Like if each of the 1000 objects are huge, you could create smaller ones with only the most relevant information in them. Then check the options you mentioned again. Another way would be to download the whole large dataset (at home) via Wi-Fi (or equivalent) on the mobile device before use.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to implement it in a very different way. What I usually do is  have a layered approach. In your case, perhaps you should have a first aggregation layer by state, then by city, etc. That way you never load hundreds of data points at once, which, by the way, is not what your user wants: They're usually looking for something specific or aggregated data - but never looking for thousands of results to browse through manually.

Comment: *never looking for thousands of results to browse through manually.* Oddly enough, after testing with real users this has been the biggest request we've gotten. The data source this is replacing has all items listed (in a PDF) which they manually browse through from top to bottom!

Comment: How can a human being process thousands of lines of data and produce something of interest out of it without any mistake? I guess they just have time to waste. In 2015, hardcore data processing is supposed to be done by computers :-)

Comment: Agreed, 100%! Sadly our attempts so far at making it 'easier' have met with pushback from those who prefer to scan the data sequentially by eyeball :(